# swift drawing shape from class in another viewcontroller (programatically)

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

I'm in the early stages of making a simple chart. However, I'm having quite some trouble drawing the shape programatically.

I've tried a bunch of variations of this:

```
let donutChart = CounterView(frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
cellView.addSubview(donutChart)
```

There's no errors, but for the past 2 days, I havn't been able to make it draw anything on the screen.

The class I'm attempting to draw is this:

```
import UIKit

let NoOfGlasses = 8
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

class CounterView: UIView {

var counter: Int = 5 {
    didSet {
        if counter <=  NoOfGlasses {
            //the view needs to be refreshed
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}

var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // 1
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

    // 2
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

    // 3
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

    // 4
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
    let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 4

    // 5
    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
        radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth/2,
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        clockwise: true)

    // 6
    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
}
```

Which should result in this basic shape:

[image]

Any help as to how I get this shape drawn in my view controller programatically would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your class in a Playground.  I was able to get it to draw with the following commands:

```
let myview = CounterView()
myview.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,300,300)
myview.counter = 5
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Donut chart in Swift Playground]

Comment: I haven't done much with playgrounds other than testing out basic language constructs. How does creating views work? It just creates a popover that shows the view?

Comment: Yes.  Just click on the Quick Look icon (eyeball) and it shows the view in a pop up.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add your CounterView of a subview of some view that's on-screen?

Comment: `cellView.addSubview(donutChart)` should be doing that, correct ?

Comment: You should add subviews to cellView.contentView. Also, why do you create your view with an origin of (100, 100)? Unless the cell is really tall that's going to position it very far down and to the right. (Is this an iPad-only app? How tall are your cells?)

Comment: my "cellView" is what I called my contentView for my cell. As for the 100,100,100,100 it was just testing for drawing it out. After the question got answered and I got it to draw correctly, I changed it to draw with constraints instead of course.